# IDE Conditional Block Highlighting

Tags: c#, c++, c, ide, development-environment

SETUP:

Imagine I have a pretty good size program, and #defines and various means of including/excluding various pieces of code are in use.

I.E. Suppose I have a piece of code like this

example_file.c:

```
include <definition_file>

#ifdef THIS
  do something really cool here
#ifdef THAT
  do something even cooler
#endif
#endif
```

definition_file.c:

```
#define THAT TRUE
#define THIS FALSE
```

Right now I don't know that neither statement will be included or used unless I look in definition. The above is a simple example, but suppose you have say 50 ifdefs and they're nested in varying ways, tracking down what each of the 50 values are is kinda a pain in the butt.

QUESTION:

Does a program/environment exist that would for example gray out or highlight the entire piece of code indicating that based on your "control file" they won't be included or will be included. (some sort of visual or other indication)

NOTE:
If someone can improve the name or the question please by all means, I'm really at a loss what to call this. (or suggest better tags too)

Comment: You may want to change things to #ifdef THIS ... #else ... #endif. Just a suggestion

Comment: @vcsjones, C# also supports this conditional compilation mechanism, with almost-identical syntax (the changes are tacked on `#define`).

Comment: @dBeer I'm not sure what I follow the suggestion, I am just showing an example of nested if's that are occuring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 will do this for both C++ (with various degrees of success) and C# (100% reliable).

I assume you don't want to hear about alternatives involving code refactoring (polymorphism, different libraries and choosing at link time what to link to, etc.)

Comment: I think it's too late/not enough time for your alternative suggestion.

Comment: Just figured I'd throw that out there; I answered his direct question to the letter anyway :)

Comment: Oh, sure, and maybe he's lucky and can do it.

Comment: Can it do it with custom "conditionals" I.E. if I'm not using a standard industry syntax? Also I'm using Ada...but the specific language I figured would be irrelevant since I'm looking more at the conditional pre se...

Comment: Blindy, I'm not sure what your second statement is referring to, I'm interested, but I'm not sure the best avenue to discuss as they like these kinds of topics to stay actually on stack overflow)

Comment: Not sure if it works with "custom" syntax, VS is pretty specialized. As to your second question, we can talk about it in comments or whatever, if you have further questions about what I said.

Comment: Well you're welcome to explain what you mean about the alternatives, I'm not sure it will help the situation I'm currently working on, but it'll be good to know. Basically, I do want to hear about said alternatives (and what you have to say about them)

Comment: @onaclov2000, basically, instead of splicing chunks of code depending on defines, you can instead have different libraries, one for each set of switches (if there aren't that many) and you link the right one at link time (or you can go the .cpp route and compile the right one based on switches). Or you can choose at run-time with derived classes. It's all based on your specific problem!

Comment: Ok I understand, I don't believe that would be feasible with my particular problem., but will be helpful in the future!

Comment: Ive selected your answer however ill continue to look for language independent conditional highlighting

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse (with CDT) also does this.

Comment: Can it do it with custom "conditionals" I.E. if I'm not using a standard industry syntax?

Comment: CDT does C/C++, so I assume it's only supporting the `cpp` conditionals.